# sql server 2008 date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

Suppose i have a table with date as

```
2010-04-25 
2010-05-25 
2010-06-25 
2010-07-25 
2010-08-25 
2010-09-25 
2010-10-25 
2010-11-25 
2010-12-25 
2011-25-25 
2011-02-25 
2011-03-25
```

then if i pass year = 2010 and month = 10, i need to get dates less than or equal to the passed year and date.

OR

Simply, how can i compare dates regardless of DAY?

Comment: like 2010-09 vs 2010-10? Or return true for 2010-10-01 = 2010-10-02?

Comment: What is the **real question** based on your comment to Serge's answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
... WHERE DATEPART(yy, `field1`) = datepart(yy, `field2) AND DATEPART(m, `field1`) = datepart(m, `field2)
```

Comment: No. Suppose i have a table with date as 2010-04-01
2010-05-01
2010-06-01
2010-07-01
2010-08-01
2010-09-01
2010-10-01
2010-11-01
2010-12-01
2011-01-01
2011-02-01
2011-03-01    then if i pass 2010-02-20, i need to get dates less than the passed date. how ?

Comment: @Rauf Nicole: Hey, that's a completely different question!

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @dates table (userdate datetime)
insert into @dates values ('2010-04-01')
insert into @dates values ('2010-05-01')
insert into @dates values ('2010-06-01')
insert into @dates values ('2010-07-01')
insert into @dates values ('2010-08-01')
insert into @dates values ('2010-09-01')
insert into @dates values ('2010-10-01')
insert into @dates values ('2010-11-01')
insert into @dates values ('2010-12-01')
insert into @dates values ('2011-01-01')
insert into @dates values ('2011-02-01')
insert into @dates values ('2011-03-01')


select * from @dates 
where userdate <  cast('2010-05-01' as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare dates with the usual comparison operators. <, <=, >, >=, ==, !=

```
select * from table where date < '02/20/2010'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same month they'll have no month difference according to DATEDIFF

```
...
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(month, value1, value2) = 0
```

In adjacent months:

```
...
WHERE
   ABS(DATEDIFF(month, value1, value2)) <= 1
```

Edit: now we have the actual question

Just use this to ignore day. There is no need to separate month and year.

```
WHERE
   DATEDIFF(month, MyColumn, @value) < 0
```

Comment: where 
  ( DATEPART(month,V1.date) <= DATEPART(month,@date) AND DATEPART(year,V1.date) = DATEPART(year, @date))
 OR
  ( DATEPART(year,V1.date) < DATEPART(year, @date))